# How to be notified of internet connection down, but WiFi still connected

Tags: java, android, network-programming

Does anybody know if it's possible to be notified in Android of a dropped internet connection while connected to WiFi? I'd like to do this without pinging if possible. For example, my app could be downloading a file over WiFi when the internet connection goes out. The device could still be connected to the wireless router, but no longer be able to download the file.

I looked at briefly at ConnectivityManager, but it seems like it only has intents for switching from 3G to WiFi or losing a specific modality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of your device, having an active WiFi connection *is* being connected to the Internet.  Having your house's DSL modem disconnect is not really any different than having the telco's junction box melt, except one is likely to be fixed faster.

If you want to monitor connectivity to a particular service, you'll have to devise a different scheme than just looking at the network stack.